# Looking for a description of "sensors" column in glances system monitoring tool

Tags: benchmarking, system-monitoring

glances provides a "top-like" display with a list of sensors and what temperature those sensors are reporting. One in particular is named "edge". Can someone explain where or what this sensor is?
I ran some benchmarking software on my older amd gpu (rx590) and my cpu fan starts spinning very fast but cpu Composite temperature is in the 40C range. cpu usage is minimal.
This sensor marked as "edge" shows a temperature around 75C.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the 'edge' sensor is the Video Card temperature.
I don't have any documentation to reference but whenever the gpu is very busy the temperature increases.